# Ubuntu 14.04 not responding

Tags: keyboard, wine, mouse, freeze

I was reinstall Ubuntu, remove Window OS, Format all my HHD and when Im using computer normal, I dont open more program( include: FireFox, Skype), on FireFox I opened 8 tabs. program run in background include Apache, php, mySQL, ibus Unikey.

My computer have structure:

HHD: 1Tb include three partitions (all have Patition type Ext4)

- swap: /dev/sda1 => 7,2 GB
- filesystem: /dev/sda2  => 102 GB
- Extended Partition: /dev/sda3 =>  891 GB

  +) Data: /dev/sda5 => 307 GB

  +) Develop: /dev/sda6 => 583 GB

RAM: 2.5GB
Main: Gigabyte G41
Chip Core 2 Dou.

the first time, I cant use keybroad, light on keyroad is Off, after about 5 second, light on mouse Off too and I must hard reset computer.

Please help me. I like Linux and I dont want comeback to Window.

Comment: Sounds like a possible hardware issue. Are there issues in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** You're going to change advanced boot parameters for Ubuntu. *Make a [system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) first!*

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following command:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and append `atkbd.reset` to its end. For example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"
   ```

   Save the file and close the editor.
3. Execute the following command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   to update GRUB's configuration file.

On the next reboot, your problem will be solved.

[<sub>source</sub>](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 3 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much but still have problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was delete other post. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard? Or the same keyboard in another port?  Have you tried unplugging the mouse?  Maybe you have a hardware problem...